# Can i use display flex but only with images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

this is what i am going for (with the bags) https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUh9O.png

and this is what i have right now https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1GhW.png

here's the css:

```
 <!--listing-->
.listing{}
    
.listing{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:60px;
    width:35%;
}

.listing p {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#0000;
}

.price {
    color: #f76f46;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:100px;
}
```

and html:

```
<!--main section-->
<div class="listing">
    <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    
    <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    
    <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
</div>
```

if i use display:inline-flex; instead of inline-block in the css, it ends up like this instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/O65l2.png

is there a way for the text to stay under each picture?

Comment: You need to add a wrapper for img + p, that way you can change flex-direction to column for them and text will be under image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each of the img and p tags in a div like so...

```
<div class="listing">
   <div class="col1">
       <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
       <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center">
          <b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br>
          <span class="price center">$76.00</span>
       </p>
   </div>

   <div class="col1">
       <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
       <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center">
          <b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br>
          <span class="price center">$76.00</span>
       </p>
   </div>

   <div class="col1">
       <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
       <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center">
          <b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br>
          <span class="price center">$76.00</span>
       </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And use css flex layout to align them each side by side:

```
.listing {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: i had to add a .listing img{} tag to resize my images bc they shrunk but this works great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the `flex` implementation.

```css
.listing {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-container {
  width: 35%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.listing p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #0000;
}

.price {
  color: #f76f46;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="listing">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span
        class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span
        class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span
        class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a flex container around each pair of image/text:

```
<!--main section-->
<div class="listing">

  <div class="myFlexContainer">
    <img src="pinkbag.png" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
  </div>

</div>


.myFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `inline-grid and` grid-template-columns

Put `display: inline-grid;` and `grid-template-columns:  auto auto auto;`
in to the parent container.

**And Don't Forget To put each listing in a `div`**

to adjust the number of grid columns change the number of `auto` in `grid-template-columns`

More in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

```css
<!--listing-->
.listing{}
    
.listing{

    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns:  auto auto auto;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:60px;
    width:100%;
}

.listing p {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#0000;
}

.price {
    color: #f76f46;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:100px;
}
```

```html
<!--main section-->
<div class="listing">
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-elegant-female-bag-two-260nw-1032419707.jpg" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-elegant-female-bag-two-260nw-1032419707.jpg" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-elegant-female-bag-two-260nw-1032419707.jpg" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-elegant-female-bag-two-260nw-1032419707.jpg" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-elegant-female-bag-two-260nw-1032419707.jpg" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-elegant-female-bag-two-260nw-1032419707.jpg" class="center">
    <p style="color:#3d5791;" class="center"><b>Extra Large Madison Handbag</b><br><span class="price center">$76.00</span></p>
    </div>
    

</div>
```

Comment: i got a checkerboard pattern instead? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Serpt.png

Comment: I got a mistake. Now it's fixed

Comment: That's because I forgot to put the `img`+`p` in a container